# Problems with SQL Parameters in C# on UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, ado.net

I'm trying to update data. Whenever I use a parameterized query it gives me the error `Fatal Error Encountered during command execution`.

Here is my code:

```
public void updateAccount(Int32 cashierid, string cashieruser, string isadmin, string cashierfname, string cashiermname, string cashierlname, string cashierpass)
{
    con.ConnectionString = conString;     
    String sql = "UPDATE cashieraccount SET cashieruser = ?cashieruser, cashierpass = ?cashierpass, isadmin = ?isadmin, cashierfname = ?cashierfname, cashiermname = ?cashiermname, cashierlname = ?cashierlname";
    sql += "WHERE cashierid = ?cashierid";
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cashieruser", cashieruser);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cashierpass", cashierpass);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?isadmin", isadmin);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cashierfname", cashierfname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cashiermname", cashiermname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cashierlname", cashierlname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cashierid", cashierid);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); **//Fatar Error Encountered during command execution**
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm missing a white-space behind your parameters, before the `where` clause:

```
String sql = "UPDATE cashieraccount SET cashieruser = ?cashieruser, cashierpass = ?cashierpass, isadmin = ?isadmin, cashierfname = ?cashierfname, cashiermname = ?cashiermname, cashierlname = ?cashierlname";
sql += " WHERE cashierid = ?cashierid";
// here ^
```